# Control de errores Scanner.hasNextDouble

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy haciendo este programa pero me salta siempre a error aunque introduzca el parámetro correcto, ¿sabéis por qué puede ser?

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project       Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package estructuresderepeticio;

/**
*
* @author carlos
*/
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JudoNew3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Double pes;


        boolean pesReal = false;



        System.out.println("digam el pes: ");

        pesReal = Scan.hasNextDouble();

        if (pesReal) {
            pesReal = false;

            pes = Scan.nextDouble();

            if (pes > 25 && pes < 65) {
                System.out.println("Peso registrado. ");
                pesReal = true;

            } else {
                System.out.println("El niño esta fuera del peso permitido ");

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(" Peso incorrecto, introduzca un numero real");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Que error te da?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se que error te da... Y un detalle, el nombre de las variables es en minúscula, es decir, scan > OK; Scan > No, ya que es una variable. Tu código quedaría:

```
package help;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JudoNew3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double pes;
        boolean pesReal = false;

        System.out.println("digam el pes: ");
        pesReal = scan.hasNextDouble();
        if (pesReal) {
            pesReal = false;

            pes = scan.nextDouble();
            if (pes > 25 && pes < 65) {
                System.out.println("Peso registrado. ");
                pesReal = true;

            } else {
                System.out.println("El niño esta fuera del peso permitido ");

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Peso incorrecto, introduzca un numero real");
        }

        // Cierra el flujo de Scanner.
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

La salida con datos no numéricos:

```
digam el pes: 
ge
Peso incorrecto, introduzca un numero real
```

La salida con números incorrectos (Usar "." y no ","):

```
digam el pes: 
54.2
Peso incorrecto, introduzca un numero real
```

La salida con un dato correcto, pero fuera de rango:

```
digam el pes: 
19999,4
El niño esta fuera del peso permitido
```

Y la salida con dato correcto y dentro de rango:

```
digam el pes: 
50,0
Peso registrado.
```

Yo desde luego, no veo que exista un error.

> Información: 
>   Cuando generamos código, Java interpreta los valores decimales con un ".", es decir, si queremos dar valor a:

```
double miValorDecimal = 1.5;// Usamos "." y no ","
```

> Ahora bien, en la ejecución es distinto... por qué? porque tenemos el
>   teclado configurado a Español, por tanto, en consola, los decimales
>   pasan a ser como los usamos siempre, es decir, en consola pondremos:

```
Introduzca un valor decimal:
6,5
```

Así funcionan los decimales en Java y en la consola de Java, es una forma coloquial de decirlo, para saber como configurar eclipse para evitar esto, o usar métodos especializados, eso ya es harina de otro costal. Tenemos a San Google.

Comment: Pues cuando introduzco un peso que esta dentro del parametro me muestra por consola esto

Comment: run:
digam el pes: 
35.5
 Peso incorrecto, introduzca un numero real
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

Comment: Y fijate. La salida con un dato correcto, pero fuera de rango:          digam el pes: 
19994.4
 Peso incorrecto, introduzca un numero real
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)   cuando no deberia

Comment: Edito mi respuesta, para añadir más información.

Comment: Que gorqui soy, jajaja, claro cuando metia e dato en vez de poner 55.5 tengo que uilizar la coma, asi no me casca el error, gracias.